# How do I display dynamic field values in a template?

Tags: nodes

I am making a module, each time user make content type and add fields to it, all its field values get rendered into static template dynamically.

For this, I am using [`noad_load_multiple()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) to get all node values of selected content type and using [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7), displaying it in a static template page.

```php
$compfields = [node_load_multiple][2](array(), array('type' => $node_type));

return theme('component_fields',array('compfields' => $compfields));
```

In the template file, I am using the following code, looping over `$compfields`.

```php
print '<p>' . $value->body['und']['0']['value'] . '</p>';
```

I know my content type has a *body* field which is rendered with `print '<p>' . $value->body['und']['0']['value'] . '</p>';`.

How can I render the additional fields added to a content type without knowing their field type?

Comment: Sounds bizarre, why aren't you using the Manage Display tab of the content type?

Comment: Your code is susceptible to XSS attacks. Unless you understand what that means, and why it's bad, you shouldn't be doing what you're doing. Get a more experienced developer to help you, at least

Comment: @clive can you give an example of good module so that I can learn coding standards against XSS attack?

Comment: Read all of the links here: https://www.drupal.org/developing/best-practices, and everything those inner pages link out to as well. There's a lot of ground to cover

Answer (score 0):

You could run a 'foreach' on the items in the list. Added fields will be named 'field_ ...' which is easy to check. The fields come with their own render functions, also available in the field object code. Although i think drupal_render() will handle it correctly anyway.

A first step could be to use dsm($compfields) to identify the field structure and then use it. (dsm is part of the devel module and displays structures in nicely readable format)

Comment: you mean to say check condition on every type of field, that  if my field is of type text, render `$value->text`. If field is of type summary or text area, follow `$value->body['und']['0']['value']` pattern, if it's an image field follow xyz pattern??

Comment: yes, that seems like a straightforward way, since you are in control of 'when a field is added' so caching will be no issue, nor the multiple reruns.  btw is it drupal 7 or 6? and check out drupal_render of a field, it will handle the different theme functions itself.

Comment: its drupal 7. Ok, I will go with this approach. But I think, it will gonna be too lengthy. Any short cut or function that can directly recognize every dynamic field and behave accordingly?